# How to build node.js project for Raspberry pi with PKG(npm) from Windows 10 or Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: node.js, linux, pi

I need to make an executable of my node.js project for Raspberry Pi.
I installed npm, node, and pkg successfully.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg

```
sudo npm install -g pkg
```

When I call the below command the process starts and hangs for more than 10 hours at

```
sudo pkg MyApp.js --target linux-armv7
.....
make  [         ] 0%
```

Same project if I build from Windows10 VS Studio Code with Windows Node.js.

Also from Ubuntu 20.04 system, I get the result in 2 seconds.

But Windows/Ubuntu build doesn't support `--target linux-armv7`
If I set `--target linux` I get the executable in 2 seconds.

And that executable doesn't work in Raspberry pi because it doesn't build for Armv7.

There should be some tweaking to make a `--target linux-armv7` from Window10 or Ubuntu Linux.

We can't spend 24 hours on a single executable build.
If any future correction on the code again takes 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Answer on the behalf of OP:

> I have finally found a solution for my issue by adding node version on the -t option.